# Change system language from Chinese to English?

Tags: languages

So I bought an Android phone that is shipped from China. The default language is Chinese. All the preinstalled apps are in Chinese. I live in the US and do not know Chinese and would like to know if there is any way to change this. When I dial a number there is a row of Chinese letters on the screen. I want to switch the language to English.

Comment: Go to Settings>Language and input>Language and pick English if provided already or download English language pack from the options.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

- Go to Settings [app look like "Gear" Sign]

[image]

- Go to language and Input [Find "A" sign icon]

[image]

- Change the Language, usually the top option is used as Changing Languages

[image]

- You will get a list of languages, select your appropriate language, That's it!

Original Source :

https://rumorscity.com/2014/12/25/how-to-change-the-language-on-android-from-chinese-to-english/

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading an app called morelocale 2 (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale), you should be able to change your language with that.

If it doesn't work there are other apps that should do the trick:
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=morelocale%202